# using "it" in this sentence

Tags: pronouns

I'm confused about using pronouns in sentences. In this sentence:

> The control plane acts as a middleware and through its global view of
>   all devices, **....** can play an important role in improving and accelerating
>   network management.

should I add "it" before "can" or it's unnecessary? or is there a better way to state this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

You can write the sentence either way.

> The control plane acts as a middleware and (through its global view of all devices) can play an important role in improving and accelerating network management.

Here the bracketted part is used only to add some extra information.

> The control plane acts as a middleware and through its global view of all devices it can play an important role in improving and accelerating network management.

Here **it** explicitly specifies the subject.

 Both ways are correct and grammatical.

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't we use a comma before "it" in the second sentence?

Comment: @Pablo Only if you also put a comma before *through*, turning the phrase inside the comma pair into nonrestrictive information.

Comment: I might put a comma before the first *and* in the second sentence: "The control plane acts as a middleware, and through its global view of all devices it can play an important role..." because "acts as a middleware" is one thing the control plane does; the rest of the sentence is something else the control plane does. The sentence can also be divided here: "The control plane acts as a middleware. Through its global view of all devices it can play..." - because the *it* is the subject.